# How can I run a Luminus project which uses Overtone?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, luminus, overtone

I'm writing a web app which uses Overtone. When I try running the app using `lein run` or when I try to start the repl while in the project's directory I get the same error: `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at clojure.main.<clinit>(main.java:20) Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Server needs to be connected before you can perform this action.`

It seems to me that both of those actions make all the files in my project compile. Is there any way to compile the namespaces which use Overtone after I run the server? Or maybe this isn't the issue, and the problem is coming from something else?

Here is my project.clj file:

```
(defproject comusic "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"

  :dependencies [[buddy "1.3.0"]
                 [compojure "1.5.2"]
                 [conman "0.6.3"]
                 [cprop "0.1.10"]
                 [funcool/struct "1.0.0"]
                 [luminus-immutant "0.2.3"]
                 [luminus-migrations "0.3.0"]
                 [luminus-nrepl "0.1.4"]
                 [markdown-clj "0.9.98"]
                 [metosin/muuntaja "0.1.0"]
                 [metosin/ring-http-response "0.8.2"]
                 [mount "0.1.11"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.5"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "42.0.0"]
                 [org.webjars.bower/tether "1.4.0"]
                 [org.webjars/bootstrap "4.0.0-alpha.5"]
                 [org.webjars/font-awesome "4.7.0"]
                 [org.webjars/jquery "3.1.1"]
                 [org.webjars/webjars-locator-jboss-vfs "0.1.0"]
                 [ring-webjars "0.1.1"]
                 [ring/ring-core "1.6.0-RC1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.2.3"]
                 [selmer "1.10.7"]
                 [overtone "0.10.1"]]

  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"

  :jvm-opts ["-server" "-Dconf=.lein-env"]
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :test-paths ["test/clj"]
  :resource-paths ["resources"]
  :target-path "target/%s/"
  :main ^:skip-aot comusic.core
  :migratus {:store :database :db ~(get (System/getenv) "DATABASE_URL")}

  :plugins [[lein-cprop "1.0.1"]
            [migratus-lein "0.4.4"]
            [lein-immutant "2.1.0"]]

  :profiles
  {:uberjar       {:omit-source    true
                   :aot            :all
                   :uberjar-name   "comusic.jar"
                   :source-paths   ["env/prod/clj"]
                   :resource-paths ["env/prod/resources"]}

   :dev           [:project/dev :profiles/dev]
   :test          [:project/dev :project/test :profiles/test]



   :project/dev   {:dependencies   [[prone "1.1.4"]
                                    [ring/ring-mock "0.3.0"]
                                    [ring/ring-devel "1.5.1"]
                                    [pjstadig/humane-test-output "0.8.1"]]
                   :plugins        [[com.jakemccrary/lein-test-refresh "0.18.1"]]

                   :source-paths   ["env/dev/clj"]
                   :resource-paths ["env/dev/resources"]
                   :repl-options   {:init-ns user}
                   :injections     [(require 'pjstadig.humane-test-output)
                                    (pjstadig.humane-test-output/activate!)]}
   :project/test  {:resource-paths ["env/test/resources"]}
   :profiles/dev  {}
   :profiles/test {}})
```

EDIT: After booting a SC server and trying to connect to it in my main function I still get the same error. File which contains main function:

```
(ns comusic.core
  (:require [comusic.handler :as handler]
            [luminus.repl-server :as repl]
            [luminus.http-server :as http]
            [luminus-migrations.core :as migrations]
            [comusic.config :refer [env]]
            [clojure.tools.cli :refer [parse-opts]]
            [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
            [mount.core :as mount]
            [overtone.core :as overtone])
  (:gen-class))

(def cli-options
  [["-p" "--port PORT" "Port number"
    :parse-fn #(Integer/parseInt %)]])

(mount/defstate ^{:on-reload :noop}
                http-server
                :start
                (http/start
                  (-> env
                      (assoc :handler (handler/app))
                      (update :port #(or (-> env :options :port) %))))
                :stop
                (http/stop http-server))

(mount/defstate ^{:on-reload :noop}
                repl-server
                :start
                (when-let [nrepl-port (env :nrepl-port)]
                  (repl/start {:port nrepl-port}))
                :stop
                (when repl-server
                  (repl/stop repl-server)))


(defn stop-app []
  (doseq [component (:stopped (mount/stop))]
    (log/info component "stopped"))
  (shutdown-agents))

(defn start-app [args]
  (doseq [component (-> args
                        (parse-opts cli-options)
                        mount/start-with-args
                        :started)]
    (log/info component "started"))
  (.addShutdownHook (Runtime/getRuntime) (Thread. stop-app)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (cond
    (some #{"migrate" "rollback"} args)
    (do
      (mount/start #'comusic.config/env)
      (migrations/migrate args (select-keys env [:database-url]))
      (System/exit 0))
    :else
    (do
      (overtone/connect-external-server 57110)
      (start-app args))))
```

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your lein configuration, rather, you need to start a server and wait for it to be ready before you try to connect and use overtone. Can you share the code you're using to connect?

Comment: I've booted a SC server and tried connecting to it in my main function. Still getting the same error. Edited post with the code.